# Is it safe to use a global variable to mark executing in ISR

Tags: c, embedded, interrupt, isr

I know that different architectures may provide different ways to let developer detect whether the cpu is running in ISR now, e.g. reading a register.

But I do found that in some BSP code, they use a global variable,it is called `g_in_isr`, as a flag to indicating whether cpu running in ISR. When an interrupt occurred the interrupt handler will perform `g_in_isr++` operation on entery and `g_in_isr--` on exit.

I am wondering if this way is safe on the architectures which allows nested interrupt. In most architectures, `g_in_isr++` or `g_in_isr--` is not atomic operation (am I right?), what if an high priority interrupt comes while an existing interrupt handler is doing `g_in_isr++` operation? Doesn't it cause problems?

**Update (2016-03-27)**

Yeah, I know it is architecture dependent, but I want to know the general case. Let us assume that `g_in_isr++` is not atomic, it is indeed not atomic on most architecture, am I right? Of course we also don't use any compiler magic to make it atomic.

Now at such a case, would it cause problems?

Comment: It might, it could, it's up to the OS designer to ensure it does not.   This is an OS design issue, not C -specific.

Comment: What CPU and what CPU instructions are generated by the compiler for those C statements?  Do interrupts need to be enabled within the ISR to allow for nested interrupts?

Comment: @kkrambo Sorry, I have updated my question so it may looks cleared now. May you answer it now? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The C language did not specify useful atomic semantics prior to C11, but one thing exists. The type `sig_atomic_t` is an integer with guaranteed atomic access, cf. ISO 9899:1999 §7.14 ¶2:

> 2 The type defined is
>
> ```
> sig_atomic_t
> ```
>
> which is the (possibly volatile-qualified) integer type of an object that can be accessed as an atomic entity, even in the presence of asynchronous interrupts.

If you use a global variable of type `sig_atomic_t` to indicate that a signal was delivered, that is safe. However, there are no operations like *atomic increment* defined in C99.

In the C11 language, you could use an `_Atomic int` for this purpose. Operations on this type work as expected.

Comment: Sorry but I was not willing to know how to tell the compiler to generate an atomic operation for me. I have updated my question so it may looks cleared now. May you re-read it now? Thanks!